# Apple TV App lacks TV Plus tab after update to Big Sur; only showing Library tab

Tags: macos, appletv, bug, big-sur, tv.app

**What I am seeing**

[image: Library tab only]

**What I should be seeing**

[image]

I can still watch content by first finding the show on the web then allowing it to open the content within the TV.app, however, this is suboptimal. How would I get my tabs back?

Comment: If you make a new account after restarting, does that new user account on the Mac show the same issue?

Comment: I've seen this myself, and it seems (for me) to be some glitch in contacting Apple's servers.  Toggling the Wifi/Ethernet on and off sometimes works, if restarting just the app itself doesn't work.  It's more common on my iPad than my Mac.

Comment: Not sure about a new user account. Toggling Wifi or restarting the app does not make any difference for me. It's been great before the update :/

Comment: The only way for me to get it to load is to open their site in Safari (https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-plus/) and to click on "Watch now", which will open the dashboard inside the app (still without the tabs showing).